# windows Shell Script not working with VB editor

Tags: wsh

Can anyone tell me why this code:

```
Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")

strcomputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName

MsgBox strcomputerName

Pcname = Mywb.Cells(4, 3).Value

If strcomputerName = Pcname Then

MsgBox "Hi Vivek!!"

End If
```

works in a vbs file but when it's put in as code in a VB Editor I get Runtime Time Error 424 - Object required?
What library do I need to reference? 
am using Ms Excel 2010.
I have tried adding below libraries in reference:

MS scripting runtime
MS script control 
and Windows script host object model
None of these seem to work for me.

Comment: What "VB Editor" are you referring to? And what version of it?

Answer (score 0):

Late binding with Excel 2010 using an object variable

Tools-->Reference-->Microsoft 14.0 Object Library

```
Dim strComputerName As String
Dim objWS As Object

Set objWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
strComputerName = objWS.ComputerName
MsgBox strComputerName

Set objWS = Nothing
```